# Why am I getting a Cannot POST /api/ error when trying to post to a form?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, routes

I have a basic website and am running into a problem. I am extremely new to this and can not seem to fix it.

When I run the server and browse to http://localhost:3000/class/create everything works fine. However, when I try to add a student I receive a message on the browser that says

" Cannot POST /api/create " and a 404 error in the console.

What is supposed to happen: The console logs "creating a student entry"

## index.js

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

// loading body-parser
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

// loading our routers
const mainRouter = require('./mainRoutes.js')
const classRouter = require('./classRoutes.js')

// tell Express to use bodyParser for JSON and URL encoded form bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

// mounting the routers
app.use('/', mainRouter)
app.use('/class', classRouter)

app.listen(3000)
console.log('Express server running on port 3000')
```

## classRoutes.js

```
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const classList = [] // our class list array

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'class', 'index.html'))
})

router.get('/create', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'class', 'create.html'))
})

// RESTful api
router.get('/api/list', function (req, res) {
  res.json(classList) // Respond with JSON
})

router.get('/api/get/:id', function (req, res) {
  res.json(classList[req.params.id]) // Notice the wildcard in the URL?
  // Try browsing to /api/get/0 once you've added some entries
})


router.post('/api/create', function (req, res) {
  console.log('creating a student entry')
})

module.exports = router
```

## create.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Class List: Create</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/api/create" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="studentName">Enter The Student's Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="student" name="student">
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

## Chrome Dev Tools output (network tab)

[image]

Comment: there is no response

Comment: @NicolasI sorry?

Comment: What does the Network tab in the Chrome Dev Tools when you do the request?

Comment: @zishone I have attached the dev tool output when i try the request

Comment: Because there is no route at that location.

Comment: @KevinB I don't undertand

Answer (score -1):

because you set `app.use('/class', classRouter);` `/class` must precede `/api/create` so the correct route is`/class/api/create`

use the correct absolute path: `action="/class/api/create"`

Comment: I've tried this but it still is not working